# Android application problems in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'm a .NET developer but I like JAVA so in my free time I play around with that. I don't normally use Eclipse but I installed the ADT eclipse plugin and Andriod SDK and I started learning and I made a new project with a TableLayout and it kinda looks good, and it runs ok on the emulator.

However... there a few things that drive me absolutely catatonic and perhaps I am doing something wrong so please help me out.
Firstly, if I change the main.xml file in whatever way, even by adding what is supposedly a correct parameter, it will start freaking out and will generate an error that just says "error" without specifying what that is, it will then generate a main.out.xml and then report an error that the main.out.xml is empty. It later won't let me delete that and will start generating a main.out.out.xml and so forth, even after I correct that original xml that caused the error.

The only way to get things going is to delete the bin folder, restart Eclipse, delete all the out xml files and then sometimes it will run the application or some other times it will start generating those 'out' files again and the loop goes on.

That way it takes hours to run a simple app even one without errors that used to run before.
Surely that was NOT how they intended it to work, is it?? 
Also.. there is no "Rebuild" button that will flush all files out automatically, or is it hidden somewhere? I am tired of manually deleting those automatically generated files and the build folder and all those out.xml files.

Also, while I'm at it, I also want to point out that the designer view sometimes disappears and there is nothing on earth that will bring it back, the only way is to create a new project and copy the main.xml to it and then it shows up again. Another bug?

I have the latest eclipse version:
Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

If you have any clues how to get this to work, I will appreciate it!
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Did you enable build-->recompile?

Comment: No where is that? the only options I see are "Run" and "Debug"

Comment: Project Menu has these options. Check that build automatically option. After that when you right click and refresh the project, it should clean and rebuild. This way you can avoid all those manual steps you are doing.

Comment: Don't ever click the 'run' icon (white triangle in green circle) when a .xml file has focus in the editor, it always causes a main.out.xml to be generated. You should use the drop down (down pointing triangle) next to it to run a project. I don't know why it makes the out.out etc files though

Comment: For some reason, if your Eclipse is an Eclipse for web development, it generates this .xml.out files when you try to run your application. Just install another version of Eclipse without these web plugins, or just don't ever try to run the application when you are editing an xml file.

Comment: NickT was right. To ensure successfully launching your Android application, you can only click the 'run' icon when you are seeing a java file in the main editor, otherwise a out.xml file will be generated and you will not be able to build your project. You can right click the name of your project, and choose `Run as Android Application`, now there should be no errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you click the Run button with an XML file selected, Eclipse is running an XSL Transformation on that XML and producing the `.out.xml` file as the result. This is a feature of the Eclipse Web Tools feature, which you'll have if you installed the Eclipse for **Java EE Developers** package (it may be included in other packages, too).

As others have said above in the comments, to run your Android app, select the Project, right-click, and choose **Run As** > **Android App**. Once you've done that once, it will create a Launch Configuration that you can launch from the **Run** or **Debug** toolbar buttons (pressing the small down-arrow on the **Run** or **Debug** buttons brings up a list of Launch Configurations that you can select from, as well as an option to manage them).

There is a Preference that will make Eclipse always launch the last thing you ran or debugged, instead of trying to be smart about what is currently selected. Open the Preferences and navigate to **Run/Debug** > **Launching**; there you'll find the option under Launch Operation at the bottom of the window.

Comment: That certainly helped a GREAT deal with all the errors. It now builds and runs without all those errors! Thank goodness

Comment: beautiful , that really help to save time building/debugging thanks