# Eclipse often run as XSL transformation

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, transformation

I have a problem with Eclipse, I am a Android developer, and when I edit in a `XML` layout file, I want to run as Android application with shortcut `Ctrl+F11`, but it will automatic run as **XSL Transformation**, and create a `xxx.out.xml` in current folder, how can I disable it?
Thanks for your help, and sorry my English.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636671/android-application-problems-in-eclipse/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to avoid this problem is to configure Eclipse to always launch the previously launched application. To do this navigate to `Window -> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching -> Launch Operation` and select `Always launch the previously launched application`.

I find this option to be more a lot more convenient than launching what is currently open.