# Eclipse(Indigo and juno) error editing XML Android File

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

When I edit an xml (resource android) file in Eclipse I have these errors:

```
20:23:17,196 INFO  [main] Main  - javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=null
20:23:17,198 INFO  [main] Main  - java.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\endorsed
20:23:17,202 INFO  [main] Main  - launchFile: C:\Users\Anderson\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.launching\launch\launch.xml
20:23:17,267 FATAL [main] Main  - No embedded stylesheet instruction for file: file:/C:/Users/Anderson/workspace/ControleRenda/res/layout/main.xml
org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.TransformationException: No embedded stylesheet instruction for file: file:/C:/Users/Anderson/workspace/ControleRenda/res/layout/main.xml
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.transform(JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.transform(JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.Main.main(Main.java:73)
Caused by: org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.TransformationException: No embedded stylesheet instruction for file: file:/C:/Users/Anderson/workspace/ControleRenda/res/layout/main.xml
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.transform(JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.java:214)
    ... 2 more
```

The xml code is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

The main.out file logs this error:

```
No XML content. Please add a root view or layout to your document.
```

And sometimes I have the error "Unexpected EOF".

If I edit the file in notepad or notepad++, save it in the project directory and refresh eclipse; then the project runs....

Can you help me? I have search the solution for this for days...

Thanks!

Comment: Mr. Anderson. Try cleaning the workspace again, if that fails, uninstall Eclipse and install a fresh copy, sounds like something went corrupted in there within Eclipse.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to run the file with an XSL Transformation, rather than an Android thing.  Have you double-checked it's launching the way you want?

Answer (score 2):

It might not be necessary to the remove  the xslt transformation, just go to the the file, right click on it and select `run configurations`

From there select `android` and create a new configuration. After this fill up the wizard and just click on `run` and everything will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're running into the same thing I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9637885/639520). Basically, you're invoking an XSLT transformation on the file instead of doing what you intend.

Comment: Hi, i uninstall XSL T from my Eclipse and run the project always clicking right button and choosing Android Project. It Work's thanks!

Comment: If an answer solves your problem and/or answers your question, please click the Accept button so that credit is given.